# Having trouble creating a code that solves for the solutions when x^2 + y^2 = n, where n is the input

Tags: python

Is it possible to code a program that can find the solutions without using functions? I'm not that familiar with it. The following is my attempt in Python 3.9:

```
n = int(input("enter a number: "))

while n>0:
    for x in range(0,n):
        x **= 2
        print("this is x:", x)
        for y in range(0,n):
            y **= 2
            n = x+y
            print("this is y:", y)

            if n == x+y:
                print(x,y)
            else:
                print(n, "has no solution")
```

The intended result is to find x and y when n can be any positive integer. For example, x^2 + y^2 = 9. The solutions would be (3,0) and (0,3). Thank you all who helped.

Comment: That's the equation for a circle. There are infinite solutions. If you want to draw the circle, you need to solve the equation first, then calculate whatever you want to calculate, eg `y`

Comment: n is the number, the program finds at least two solutions so when plugged into the equation, it equals to n. Not sure how it can have infinite solutions.

Comment: do you mean integer solutions?  otherwise there is an infinite amount of solutions for any n.

Comment: @dankdud How many points there are in a circle? Infinite.

Comment: I repeat, this is the equation for a circle. There are infinite solutions because there are infinite points on a circle. `3,0` and `0,3` are the coordinates where the circle intercepts the x and y axis

Comment: I just realized its close to x^2 + y^2 = r^2

Comment: It's not close. It's identical

Comment: If you want to find the intercept points, the solution is easy - replace `x` with 0 and calculate `y` eg `y=+/-sqrt(n-x^2)`. Replace `y` with 0 and calculate `x`

Comment: Also you are assigning `n = x+y` and then you check for `n == x+y` which will always be True...

Comment: n is not squared, so would there still be infinite answers?

Comment: Also you are just using integer values and this way you could end up with no solution.

Comment: @dankud n is a constant. Besides *every* number is the square of another

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I'll implement your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the task correctly, you want to solve x^2 + y^2 = n in integers. Here is my code.

```
n = int(input("enter a number: "))
sqrt = {} # key: square of integer, value: square root of it
# assume that x >= y, otherwise, swap
x = 0
while x * x <= n:
    x_square = x * x
    # check if solution exists
    if n - x_square in sqrt:
        print(f'x={x} and y={sqrt[n-x_square]} satisfy x^2+y^2={n}')
        print(f'x={sqrt[n-x_square]} and y={x} satisfy x^2+y^2={n}')
    sqrt[x_square] = x
    x += 1
```

UPD:
Your code will work as well, except you take squares of `x` and `y` too early. Even when `x` in the loop is 3, you convert it to 9 the next line. Your code can be fixed as follows.

```
n = int(input("enter a number: "))
if n < 0:
    print('No solution')
else:
    solution_found = False
    for x in range(0,n):
        for y in range(0,n):
            if n == x*x + y*y:
                print(x,y)
                solution_found = True
    if not solution_found:
        print('No solution')
```

UPD2: Fixed my solution to satisfy no function requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I truly appreciate it. I'll implement it into my code.

Comment: May you please tell me what if not solution_found does?

Comment: Sometimes, there is no solutions in integers. For example, x^2+y^2=3 has no solutions in integers. In this case, I think that printing 'No solution' would be a good idea. Therefore, I need to track if the solution is found for any combination of x and y, and if not, print No solution

Comment: To achieve this goal, I say that in the beginning `solution_found = False` (no solution is found yet), and change its value to True once a solution is found. If the loop does not find any solution, then `solution_found `is still False, so `not solution_found` is not False, i.e., it's true.

Comment: For the last two lines of your code, if `solution_found` is true, why would you print no solution?

Comment: My updated understanding is after the for loop, `solution_found = True`.  `if not solution_found` translates to if it is not true, `print("no solution")`. Is this correct?

Comment: If inside the loop solution is found, then `solution_found` becomes True, if not, then the value stays False.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily "brute force" this with a nested loop on x and y where y >=x to find inversions without running through all of them.

```
n = 9
for x in range(n):
    for y in range(x,n+1):
        if x*x + y*y == n:
            print(*{(x,y),(y,x)}) # only print one solution if x==y

(0, 3) (3, 0)
```

If you want to optimize this, you can break the loops when the remaining values exceed the target number:

```
n = 9
for x in range(n):
    if x*x > n:                    # if x^2 already greater than n
        break                      # no higher value of x will work either
    for y in range(x,n+1):
        if x*x + y*y == n:
            print(*{(x,y),(y,x)})
        elif x*x + y*y > n:        # if y already gives a result > n for this x
            break                  # then no higher value of y will work
```

A more advanced technique is to build a dictionary of squares up to n and find any value of x for which a square equal to n-x^2 exists:

```
n      = 9
y2     = {y*y:y for y in range(n+1)}
result = [(x,y2[n-x*x]) for x in range(n+1) if n-x*x in y2]

print(*result or {"no solution"}) # (0, 3) (3, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will implement your feedback in the future.